# Why is the same Job being repeated in kue?

Tags: kue

I am looping through a bunch of records in mongodb and putting them in kue for some processing, I won't put in all that code here because it really does not seem to apply but I do something like the following:

```
var record;
for(var x = 0; x < results.length; x++){    
  record = results[x];
  console.log(record);
  queue.create("process_images", record).priority('normal').save();
}
```

If there is something I shouldn't do in this case, like not create queue in a loop please point it out. But anyway when I do the console.log I get stuff like the following:

```
{ id: 5577fe8a4b795f3c068fbb10,
  collection_name: 'Image',
  data_source: 'Mongo',
  origin_dir: 'path to origin dir',
  img_src: '/uploads/images/5577/5577fe8a4b795f3c068fbb10/IMG_0158.JPG' }
{ id: 5577feb84b795f3c068fbb11,
  collection_name: 'Image',
  data_source: 'Mongo',
  origin_dir: 'path to origin dir',
  img_src: '/uploads/images/5577/5577feb84b795f3c068fbb11/IMG_0018.JPG' }
```

which is what I expect.

But in my watcher when I do the following:

```
  var queue = kue.createQueue();
  queue.on('job complete', function(id, result) {
      kue.Job.get(id, function(err, job){
        if (err) return;
        job.remove(function(err){
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Removed completed job #%d', job.id);
        });
      });
  });
  queue.process("process_images", function(job, done){
          check_it(job.data, done);
  });
  function check_it(data, done) {
      console.log("handling data");
      console.log(data);
      // email send stuff...
      done();
    }
```

I get the following:

```
Removed completed job #669
handling data
{ id: '55cd97a68c9f913608c5101b',
  collection_name: 'Image',
  data_source: 'Mongo',
  origin_dir: 'path to origin dir',
  img_src: '/uploads/images/55cd/55cd97a68c9f913608c5101b/11378154_422142334643881_2122676904_n.jpg' }
Removed completed job #670
handling data
{ id: '55cd97a68c9f913608c5101b',
  collection_name: 'Image',
  data_source: 'Mongo',
  origin_dir: 'path to origin dir',
  img_src: '/uploads/images/55cd/55cd97a68c9f913608c5101b/11378154_422142334643881_2122676904_n.jpg' }
```

again, and again, and again. All the time only that record, which implies to me that there is some async situation that I can't see, or that I have misunderstood completely how kue is going to work given that this is actually the last job that I saved. My main problem here is probably that I am sort of used to how resque does things, and this seems a little off.

Comment: hmm, I guess it is the queue.create, guess I need to do var creator = function(record){queue.create("process_images", record).priority('normal').save();}  creator(record); in the loop. Of course creator defined outside of loop.

Comment: anyway it turned out to be a closure / loop situation, and I couldn't see it.